# PyQT5 QFileDialog window title not showing on mac

Tags: python, macos, pyqt5

I made a PyQt5 application on Windows and now I want to use the application on a Mac. The app prompts the user to select a couple different files. I used the title of the QFileDialog window to let the user know which files like so:

```
    instrument_file_raw=QFileDialog().getOpenFileName(self, "Select Instrument File","","Excel (*.xlsx)")
    instrument_file_raw=str(instrument_file_raw[0])
    
    if instrument_file_raw=="":
        error_dialog = QErrorMessage(self)
        error_dialog.showMessage('No filename entered')
        return
    
    run_list_file=QFileDialog().getOpenFileName(self, "Select Run List File","","Excel (*.xlsx)")
    run_list_file=str(run_list_file[0])
    
    if run_list_file=="":
        error_dialog = QErrorMessage(self)
        error_dialog.showMessage('No filename entered')
        return
```

However when I run the same code on Mac there is no window title shown when the file explorer opens. Even if I manually set the window title by

```
instrument_file_window=QFileDialog()
instrument_file_window.setWindowTitle("Select Instrument File")
instrument_file_raw=instrument_file_window.getOpenFileName(self,"Select Instrument File","","Excel (*.xlsx)")
```

Is there a way to show the window title on Mac? How can I indicate to the user what to input?

Comment: You're probably using a macOS version higher than 10.11, right?

Comment: Yes its 10.15.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem that has not been fixed yet (see [QTBUG-59805](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-59805)) and related to a change to macOS starting from version 10.11 (El Capitan).

If you do need to display the caption, the only solution is to use the *non native* file dialog option.

```
path, filter = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
    self, "Select Instrument File", "", "Excel (*.xlsx)", 
    options=QtWidgets.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
    )
```

Note that `getOpenFileName`, like other similar functions, is a **static** function: it constructs and configure a *new* file dialog instance and then returns it. In fact, if you closely look at my code above, I didn't use any parentheses after `QFileDialog`.
Besides the options in the arguments, there's *no* way to access the created dialog if it's native, and there is only limited access for non native dialogs, but only by using complex systems (like a timer that checks for the top level widget) which are also not always reliable.

The above also means that:

1. you don't need to create a new instance, since it won't be used;
2. for the same reason, setting any property (like the window title) has absolutely no effect;

Comment: This worked I'm just a little confused what the filter variable does. It doesn't work without it

Comment: @Gingerhaze what do you mean by "it doesn't work without it"?